# guard and rspec - NOT liking my postgress :test credentials in database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rspec, guard

So I have my postgres set up as such in the database.yml

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: startpoint
  hostname: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password
```

in the terminal I generally do:

`psql -h localhous -d startpoint -U postrgres`

And it connects me to the database.

So I tried:

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: startpoint
  hostname: localhost
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password:
```

but when guard runs I get:

```
`initialize': FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres" (PG::ConnectionBad)
```

Ideas?

Comment: The same setup you are using works fine for me. Do you get the same error if you run rspec without guard? What about your development environment, does it work fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your user credentials are set correctly by creating a database and assigning ownership to your app's user to establish the connection. check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987171/rails-3-2-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-pgerror) out