# Can not connect Rails app with PostgreSQL on ubuntu

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu

i am unable to connect My rails app with PostgreSQL database which is running on my Ubuntu server running on certain instance.I created new user and password by using the following command.

```
1-sudo -u postgres createuser -s user1
2-sudo -u postgres psql.
3-postgres=\\password userpass
```

Check my database.yml file which is given below.

> database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: 100sallon_development
  pool: 5
  username: user1
  password: *******
  host: 10.*.*.*
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: 100sallon_test
  pool: 5
  username: user1
  password:  *******
  host: 10.*.*.*

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: 100sallon_production
  pool: 5
  username: user1
  password: ******
  host: 10.*.*.*
```

When i tried to create the database using the below command `rake db:create` it gave me the below error.

> Error:

```
could not connect to server:connection refused
      Is the server running on the host:10.*.*.* and accepting
      TCP/IP connections on the port 5432
```

My Ubuntu server is running on given IP.But still face problem to connect with the PostgreSQL database.Please help me to resolve this error.Thank you.

Comment: try without the host

Comment: @nik : according to you i removed the host but it is giving the error ` Fatal : Peer authentication failed for user user1.

Comment: Follow the accepted  answer in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987171/rails-3-2-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-pgerror) and your problem will be resolved

Comment: check you firewall settings. If port 5432 is open  - also validate your `pg_hba.conf` so it contains your app/client IP entries with `md5` or `trust` (not recommended).if you change pg_hba.conf - make sure to reload configuration in postgres.

Comment: what is your `listen_addresses` in postgresql.conf ?

Comment: @ alexius : Actually i am new to PostgreSQL.Can you please tell me how i will check this.

Comment: @ alexius : i checked using command `sudo netstat -tulpn` and found there this confugration `1117/TCP   0  0.0.0.0:25   0.0.0.0 LISTEN`.