# Getting error: Peer authentication failed for user “postgres”, when trying to get create database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

I am trying to create Database for the New Project in ror.

I implement this command `rake db:create`  it show me error like below.

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"postgres", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"demo_development"}
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"

Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "username"=>"postgres", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"demo_test"}
```

please help me to come out of it.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What's in your `pg_hba.conf`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987171/rails-3-2-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-pgerror

Comment: pg_hba.conf its empty @SebastiánPalma Can you help me to solve it.

Comment: Easiest solution is to try a clean installation, what OS are you using?